# multiplying two int arrays in python

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve the answer for multiplying two int arrays (output is also an int array).

For example, `num1 = [2, 2, 0], num2 = [1, 0]` will give us `[2, 2, 0, 0]`

What I tried was

```
def multiply(num1, num2):
    if num1 == [0] or num2 == [0]:
        return [0]
    sign = -1 if (num1[0] < 0) ^ (num2[0] < 0) else 1
    num1[0] = abs(num1[0])
    num2[0] = abs(num2[0])
    res = [0] * (len(num1) + len(num2) + 1) # space O(n + m)
    for i in range(len(num1) - 1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(len(num2) - 1, -1, -1):
            res[i + j + 1] += num1[i] * num2[j]
            res[i + j] += res[i + j + 1] // 10
            res[i + j + 1] %= 10
    res[0] *= sign

    return res
```

trying to imitate the grade-school multiplication.

However, in the official answer to this question, it adds these two lines to remove the leading zeros.

```
res = res[next((i for i, x in enumerate(res) if x != 0), len(res)):] or [0]
return res
```

I am so confused about how it works. It seems like it is just retrieving the indices of an array where the value is not 0, but I don't understand how `next` works with that. Also, is there a simpler way to do what it actually tries to do?

Comment: how does `[2, 2, 0] * [1, 0]` become `[2, 2, 0, 0]` ?

Comment: it denotes 220 * 10 = 2200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(i for i, x in enumerate(res) if x != 0)`

this returns a generator with indices of array where the number is not equal to 0.
So in this array:

`number = [0, 0, 4, 9]`

your code inside next `(i for i, x in enumerate(res) if x != 0)` will give a generator which has the values

`[2, 3]`

2 here is an index and refers to the 4 in the array "number" and similarly 3 here refers to 9 in the original number. and all next does is, it fetches the next value from the generator each time it is called on a generator. calling it once and for the first time return 2 from this result. which is the index of the first non 0 element from the original number.

and then we just slice the array from this index of the first non zero number to the complete length of the original array.

`res[2:]` this syntax is called slicing where 2 specifies the starting index and no value after colon signifies the enter rest of the array.

Answer (score 5):

**Explanation**

```
res = res[next((i for i, x in enumerate(res) if x != 0), len(res)):] or [0]
return res
```

In short: this gives the index of the first non-zero and slices the list from there.

- **or [0]** if given empty input this will result in returning [0]
- **res[index:]** this will return everything from given *index* onwards
- **next(iterable, something2)** get next value from *iterable*, return *something2* if *iterable* is empty. this makes sure that if a list of `0`'s is given, this will give the last index of the array
- **(i for i, x in enumerate(res) if x != 0)** this is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) creating a stream of values of all indices (*i*) of values (*x*) in the list that are not zero. The values (*x*) are not returned, only the indices (*i*).

The generator will not yield results for `0`'s, making sure the first thing `next()` can use is the first index of a nonzero. Passing back that value to the slice.

**Another solution**

Why not turn them to numbers, multiply and then convert back to list? Faster & more readable

```
def to_int(list_int):
    # This can also be done with list comprehension and powers of 10
    return int("".join(map(str, list_int)))

def to_list(integer):
    return [int(x) for x in str(integer)]


num1 = [2, 2, 0]
num2 = [1, 0]

to_list(to_int(num1) * to_int(num2))
```

> [2, 2, 0, 0]

**Performance**

Comparing to the given `multiply()`

```
%timeit multiply(num1, num2)
3.87 µs ± 44.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit to_list(to_int(num1) * to_int(num2))
2.74 µs ± 25.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: forgot to mention that this is an interview practice, so that would not be the best time and space complexity

Comment: this is from a study book, so it's just a practice. My question shows the official answer, but I just don't understand the answer.

Comment: If you care about code readability at all or expect anybody else to ever work on your code, the alternative solution is definitely the way to go. I really wouldn't want to code with someone who uses your textbook answer in real code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a pretty obscure one-liner to accomplish stripping the leading zeros. Let's break it down by simplifying different parts.

If you remove everything within the `next` call you can see it's just returning a single int index to slice the result with. If that returns an empty array, then the answer is `[0]`.

```
res = res[next(...):] or [0]
```

Now let's break down the statement inside of `next` before we talk about `next`.

```
(i for i, x in enumerate(res) if x != 0), len(res)
```

This statement is a tuple, whose first value is a generator that generates the index `i`s where the value `x` is not 0. The second value is the length of `res`.

There's an obscure trick here with `next` - if the generator that is the first value in the tuple is not empty, then `next` will return the first value from that generator which is the first index that is not a zero. If it is empty however (i.e. all digits are 0), it will return the second value `len(res)`. This result is then fed into the slice operator to remove all of the zeros - either by slicing up to the first non-zero index or slicing away the entire array.

This to me seems very convoluted. The readable pythonic way from my perspective is simply:

```
while len(res) > 1 and res[0] == 0:
    res.pop(0)
return res
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense! Do you know why the number of digits required for the product is at most `n + m` for `n` and `m` digit operands? It seems like this is the cause of leading 0 in the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to that `next` is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), which is like a list comprehension except that it makes a generator instead of a list.  It's a roundabout way to find the index of the first nonzero element of the old `res`, because the `next` here just finds the *first* value generated by the generator, and discards the rest.

I do enjoy a slick one-liner once in a while, but in this case I'd probably just write the loop explicitly.

```py
for i in range(len(res)):
    if res[i]:
        res = res[i:]
        break
else:
    res = [0]
return res
```

The [for/else](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) here saves me having to detect the `[0, 0, 0, ..., 0]` case specially.